# sound_play playWave() is not playing sound

Tags: ros, sound-play

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the directions I received in:

http://answers.ros.org/question/41385/play-a-sound-file-in-a-python-node/

I had the sound_play's soundClient functionality working for some time.

However it has inexplicably stopped working and I'm unsure as to why.

I'm starting the sound_playnode.py and running the following in another node.

The relevant lines from my node (and launch file) are:

```
<param name = "my_file" value = "file://$(find my_audio)/a_sound.wav" />

from sound_play.libsoundplay import SoundClient

soundhandle = SoundClient()
my_sound = rospy.get_param('my_file')
soundhandle.playWave(my_sound)
```

With numerous print statements I can tell that the soundhandle.playWave(my_sound) is being called and does not appear to generate an error, but no sound is played. I have tried the second method as well, but with the same results.

I can run

```
$rosrun sound_play play.py "/absolute/path/to/my_file.wav"
```

and get the sound to play every time.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43385/sound_play-playwave()-is-not-playing-sound/) by [DocSmiley](https://answers.ros.org/users/2536/docsmiley/) on ROS Answers with karma: 127 on 2012-09-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What about calling *soundhandle.playWave('/absolute/path/to/my_file.wav')*, does it work?

---

Originally posted by [kszonek](https://answers.ros.org/users/2959/kszonek/) with karma: 459 on 2012-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0